# Application of the compactness theorem

Tags: propositional-calculus

In my logic book they ask me to prove the following as a consequence of the compactness theorem for propositional logic.

Let $S \subseteq N$ be an infinite set. I have to show that there exists an infinite sequence of unequal binary numbers: $b_1,b_2,\ldots$ such that $b_i$ is a prefix of $b_{i+1}$ and also of the prefix of a number in $S$.

Can someone help me on the way to solving this as an application of the compactness theorem?

My guess is that I have to model this situation as a set of propositional formulas and show that every finite subset is satisfiable.

Comment: Are you sure this is a question about *propositional* logic? It sounds much more like a problem for *predicate* logic.

Comment: I am very sure :).

Comment: which book do you use?

Comment: It's a dutch syllabus written by one of our professors, which I do not have digitaly unfortunatly.